# Clear wxTextCtrl after thread

Tags: multithreading, wxpython

I have a ListCtrl that processes a long tasks.  During this
time I need to have a simple text "Running" populated on the wx.TextCtrl
and cleared after the threading stops. How can do this? This is what I'm
using..

```
***processing ***
    self.testThread=threading.Thread(target=self.__run)
    self.testThread.start()

def __run(self):
    self.list_inter.SetLabel("Running")
    self.testThread.stopped = True
    self.list_inter.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to send a message from the thread at the end of its execution. You would need to use one of wxPython's thread-safe methods to do that, such as wx.CallAfter or wx.PostEvent. This would allow you to call a method in your application that clears the text control.

Personally, I like to use pubsub in combination with wx.CallAfter to send a message to my application that it needs to update. You can read about how I do that sort of thing in this tutorial:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/

Sadly, that tutorial uses the old pubsub API, so if you have any problems with it, you may need to update to the slightly different, but newer API, which I've talked about [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/09/05/wxpython-2-9-and-the-newer-pubsub-api-a-simple-tutorial/).

Finally, you can always take a look at the wxPython wiki, which has lots of interesting threading examples here:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Comment: I've looked into your timer examples, http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/ I can't send a message (from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher or from pydispatch import dispatcher)  to your test Thread class.  Meaning my real process is in another panel where I send that to where you have "This is the code executing in the new thread"

Comment: I think you have it backwards. You set the TextCtrl to "Running", then you start the thread. When the thread finishes, the thread class will send a message to the GUI to tell it to clear the TextCtrl. If you want to send a message to a thread, then you need to have the thread do its work in chunks and periodically check for messages.

Comment: I changed to static text and it worked! Now I have the big picture of threading.  Appreciate that Mike.